# Ansible to loop until result is not empty

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Im trying to create a simple Ansible script that loops through a command until it returns an IP. Here is what I have

```yaml
- name: Get Shipa API address
  shell: kubectl --namespace=shipa-system get svc shipa-ingress-nginx -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}"
  environment:
    TERM: dumb      
  register: shipa_api 
  until: shipa_api.stdout | lenght > 3
  retries: 5
  delay: 90

- set_fact:
    shipa_apiaddr: '{{ shipa_api.stdout | trim }}'
```

This is surely not working and one point to note is that the command above might return a simple `%` when it is empty, so I need to make sure Ansible only moves on to the next task when there is a real IP or more than X amount of characters

How can I do this? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for a condition to check for IPs like `until: shipa_api.stdout is regex(''<ipv4-regex-here>")`?

Comment: Something along those lines. The problem is that the IP will change every time we run the ansible script, so it needs to wait until there is an IP there but I can't point a fixed IP

Comment: Sure, the regex would need to check for a generic IP address and not a single fixed IP but I agree that the `ipaddr` filter would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a filter called [`ipaddr`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html) for this.

So you could go:

```yaml
- name: Get Shipa API address
  shell: kubectl --namespace=shipa-system get svc shipa-ingress-nginx -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}"
  environment:
    TERM: dumb      
  register: shipa_api 
  until: shipa_api.stdout | ipaddr
  retries: 5
  delay: 90
```

Comment: You need `netaddr` installed to use ipaddr